# How to find a pair of basis vectors for the plane given by the equation?

Tags: calculus, vectors, mathematica

Find a pair of basis vectors for the plane given by the equation x+2y+3z=0

I was given the Hint: you can find points on the plane by choosing values for two variables and solving for the third

I am in calc III and doing this on the program Mathematica

Comment: What do you not understand about the hint?  If $y=s$ and $z=t$, how do you describe the set of solutions to $x+2y+3z=0$ in parametric form?  If you set $s=0,t=1$ what does the solution look like?  What if you set $s=1,t=0$?

Comment: So I can set the number equal to different thing? what if I set two of them to 0 and then solved?

Comment: If you set them both to zero, see what happens... you'll get $x=y=z=0$ which is not an interesting solution.  The point being is that you can find two different **linearly independent** vectors that satisfy your equation (take your pick, there are infinitely many correct answers).  So long as you pick two linearly independent vectors that both lie in your plane, they can act as a basis for the plane.  The zero vector will not work however as it is never linearly independent to anything (even if it is alone by itself).

Answer (score 1):

Any two vectors lying on the plane will do as long as they're linearly independent. A simple way to find such vectors is, as mentioned to choose two variable and solve for the third:

let $x=y=1$, then by substitution into the equation of the plane, $z=-1$

This tells you the vector $(1,1,-1)$ lies on the given plane. You can alsocheck your answer by substituting the values back in and making sure the equation is consistent:
$$(1)+2(1)+3(-1)=0$$
Then all we need to do is find another vector which satisfies this equation and isn't linearly dependent on the one we've already found.

let $x=z=1$, then by substitution, $y=-2$, so the vector $(1,-2,1)$ should lie on the plane. We'll check our answer again:
$$(1)+2(-2)+3(1)=0$$
Again, this is consistent, so we must have found a valid vector.
So, we have $(1,1,-1)$ and $(1,-2,1)$, how do we know they're linearly independent? the only way just two vectors can be linearly dependent is if they're scalar multiples of eachother, which these two vectors are obviously not. So, a valid basis for $x+2y+3z=0$ is given by:
$$B=\{(1,1,-1),(1,-2,1)\}$$

Note however, that any two linearly independent vectors lying on the given plane form a valid basis for it, its just convenient to find two such vectors via this method.